# grep to find instances of "Foo" where "Bar" does not appear within 10 lines

Tags: grep

Suppose I want to search an entire tree for all CPP files where "Foo" occurs.  I might do:

```
find . -name "*.cpp" | xargs grep "Foo"
```

Now suppose I want to list *only* those instances where some other string, say "Bar" does *not* occur within 3 lines of the previous result.

So given two files:

### a.cpp

```
1 Foo
2 qwerty
3 qwerty
```

### b.cpp

```
1 Foo
2 Bar
3 qwerty
```

I would like to construct a simple search where "Foo" from a.cpp is found, but "Foo" from b.cpp is not.

Is there a way to accomplish this in a fairly simple way?

Comment: Maybe solution could be in option grep -A and/or grep -B and/or grep -C. I'm trying but with no sucess....

Comment: @maurelio79:  My current theory is this.  Grep for "Foo" using -A 10 for context.  Pipe that to grep -v Bar.  Pipe that to sed to get the filename & line number.  Pipe that to (something?) to print that line.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep --include='\.cpp$' -rnM 'Foo(?!(?:.*\n){0,2}.*Bar)' .
```

The key is in the `-M` option which is unique to `pcregrep` and is used to match multiple lines (`pcregrep` pulls more data from the input file as necessary when walking the RE demands it).

`(?!...)` is the perl/PCRE negative look-ahead RE operator. `Foo(?!...)` matches `Foo` as long as `...` does not match what follows.

`...` being `(?:.*\n){0,2}.*Bar` (`.` not matching a newline character), that is from 0 to 2 lines followed by a line containing `Bar`.

Comment: +1:  Excellent.  Thanks so much; I'm sure it wasn't easy to figure out the correct regex.  I very much appreciate your efforts.  This seems to be working exactly as I wanted.

Comment: Side question if you care to answer.  How did you come to know about `pcregrep`?  I've never heard of it before.

Comment: @JohnDibling, I personally found out recently [on unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=pcregrep). That RE is not particularly complex, especially when you're familiar with the `(?!...)` negative look-ahead `perl` RE operator.

Answer (score 9):

Never mind, just use `pcregrep` as [suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109320/22222) by @StephaneChazelas.

---

This should work:

```
$ find . -name "*.cpp" | 
    while IFS= read -r file; do 
      grep -A 3 Foo "$file" | grep -q Bar || echo "$file"; 
    done
```

The idea is to use grep's `-A` switch to output the matched lines and the N following lines. You then pass the result through a `grep Bar` and if that does not match (exit > 0), then you echo the name of the file.

If you know you have sane file names (no spaces, new lines or other weird characters), you can simplify to:

```
$ for file in $(find . -name "*.cpp"); do 
   grep -A 3 Foo "$file" | grep -q Bar || echo "$file"; 
  done
```

---

For example:

```
terdon@oregano foo $ cat a.cpp 
1 Foo
2 qwerty
3 qwerty
terdon@oregano foo $ cat b.cpp 
1 Foo
2 Bar
3 qwerty
terdon@oregano foo $ cat c.cpp 
1 Foo
2 qwerty
3 qwerty
4 qwerty
5. Bar
terdon@oregano foo $ for file in $(find . -name "*.cpp"); do grep -A 3 Foo "$file" | grep -q Bar || echo "$file"; done 
./c.cpp
./a.cpp
```

Note that `c.cpp` is returned despite containing `Bar` because the line with `Bar` is more than 3 lines after `Foo`. You cna control the number of lines you want to search by changing the value passed to `-A`:

```
$ for file in $(find . -name "*.cpp"); do 
   grep -A 10 Foo "$file" | grep -q Bar || echo "$file"; 
  done 
./a.cpp
```

---

Here's a shorter one (assuming you use `bash`):

```
$ shopt -s globstar 
$ for file in **/*cpp; do 
    grep -A 10 Foo "$file" | grep -q Bar || echo "$file"; 
  done
```

---

#### IMPORTANT

As Stephane Chazelas pointed out in the comments, the above solutions will also print files that don't contain `Foo` at all. This one avoids that:

```
for file in **/*cpp; do 
  grep -qm 1 Foo "$file" && 
  (grep -A 3 Foo "$file" | grep -q Bar || echo "$file"); 
done
```

Comment: +1 neat-o.  Little more complex than I was hoping for, but not bad at all.

Comment: That assumes "Foo" occurs only once. That will also report the files that don't contain `Foo`. You have missing quotes.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas thanks, quotes fixed. You're quite right about reporting files with no `Foo` and I fixed that but I don't see your point about multiple instances of `Foo`. It should deal with them correctly.

Comment: @JohnDibling see updates.

Comment: It would not report a file containing 100 lines of "Foo" followed by "Bar".

Answer (score 0):

Untested, I'm on my phone :

```
find . -name "*.cpp" | xargs awk '/foo/{t=$0;c=10}/bar/{c=0;t=""}c{c--}t&&!c{print t;t=""}END&&t{print t}'
```

something like that.